# \v{d} does not work, czech letter with check

Tags: input-encodings

How do I type `d` with check? It should look something like `ď`.

Other letters like `r` or `c` do look like `\v{c}` or `\v{r}` but `t` and `d` are different when typing check over them.

I use English ASCII encoding. Can someone recommend to me a solution, so that I do not need to change encoding?

Comment: Are you using LaTeX?

Comment: I don't know czech but imho according this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_orthography the output is correct. If you really want a check you could use `\accent 7 d` (with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`)

Answer (score 6):

From your other questions, it seems you're using LaTeX. So here's how to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[czech]{babel} % recommended if you write in Czech

\begin{document}

\v{c}\v{d}\v{e}\v{n}\v{r}\v{s}\v{t}\v{z}

\v{C}\v{D}\v{E}\v{N}\v{R}\v{S}\v{T}\v{Z}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the Latin Modern fonts have better placement of the accents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[czech]{babel} % recommended if you write in Czech

\usepackage{lmodern} % better accents

\begin{document}

\v{c}\v{d}\v{e}\v{n}\v{r}\v{s}\v{t}\v{z}

\v{C}\v{D}\v{E}\v{N}\v{R}\v{S}\v{T}\v{Z}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you encode your file in UTF-8, you can also input the characters directly; the output would be the same.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel} % recommended if you write in Czech
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

čďěňřšťž

ČĎĚŇŘŠŤŽ

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have a problem with your last example in WinEdt. When I write directly čďěňřšťž

ČĎĚŇŘŠŤŽ it gives me the following error:Package Inpuenc Error:Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with latex.

Comment: Ahhh ok, when restarted and new loading as ANSI, everything goes smoothly.Thanks!